Shopify Graphql - Failed to load schema [Nuxt 3]
I am trying to connect an application of mine in nuxt 3 with shopify.
I initially created an app in Shopify and set up API Admin and Storefront API Integration.
I then installed nuxt-graphql-client on my project and configured the nuxt.config as follows:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  colorMode: {
    preference: "light",
  },
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  },

  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      "graphql-client": {
        clients: {
          default: {
            host: process.env.SHOPIFY_DOMAIN,
            token: {
              name: "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token",
              value: process.env.SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_TOKEN,
              type: null,
            },
            retainToken: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  css: ["~/assets/css/main.scss"],
  modules: [
    "@nuxt/image",
    "nuxt-icon",
    "nuxt-swiper",
    "@nuxt/ui",
    "@nuxtjs/i18n",
    "nuxt-graphql-client",
  ],
});

I set up the .env file as follows

SHOPIFY_DOMAIN=https:///admin/api/2024-04/graphql.json
SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN=

I got the token from API Credentials > Storefront API Access Token.
After starting the project it generated the following error

Failed to load schema from https:///admin/api/2024-04/graphql.json:


Can you give a try to some of those?

seems thas  value: process.env.SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_TOKEN in nuxt.config.ts is different from what you have in your .env file SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN=
SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_TOKEN & SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN
